# Extracting filenames from command line arguments with Ruby

Tags: ruby, optparse

I'm trying to use [optparse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) to parse command line arguments. I would like my program to accept arguments like that:

```
$ ./myscript.rb [options] filename
```

I can easily manage the `[options]` part:

```
require 'optparse'

options = { :verbose => false, :type => :html }

opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-v', '--verbose') do
    options[:verbose] = true
  end
  opts.on('-t', '--type', [:html, :css]) do |type|
    options[:type] = type
  end
end
opts.parse!(ARGV)
```

But how do I get the `filename`?

I could extract it manually from `ARGV`, but there has to be a better solution, just can't figure out how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "parse" method returns the unprocessed ARGV.  So in your example, it will return a one element array with the filename in it.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't just use ARGV.pop. For example
>   when the last argument is "css" it
>   could either be a file or belong to
>   --type switch.

But if your script requires the last argument to be a filename (which is what your usage output inquires) this case should never happen the script should exit with a non-zero and the user should get a usage report or error.

Now if you want to make a default filename or not require a filename as the last argument but leave it optional then you could just test to see if the last argument is a valid file. If so use it as expected otherwise continue without etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer can still be useful.

Ruby has one `built-in` variable `__FILE__` can do this type of work.

```rb
puts __FILE__
```

it will print out your file's name.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think extracting it before sending it to OptionParser is bad, I think it makes sense. I probably say this because I have never used `OptionParser` before, but oh well.

```
require 'optparse'

file = ARGV.pop
opts = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I can't just use ARGV.pop. For example when the last argument is "css" it could either be a file or belong to --type switch.

Comment: Don't do this; see the first answer as OptionParser has already provided a simple solution.